# Eigenvector centrality measures in R

Tags: r, measure, eigenvector

I have a partial correlation matrix, which consists of positive and negative values. I have constructed a network based on this matrix and want to calculate the eigenvector centrality measure for it. I am using `evcent` function, but I haven't found any documentation on how this function treats negative values in the input. Can anyone refer me to a documentation, paper etc that can explain this clearly? I seem to be pretty confused on this measure.

I have put my code here for reference. Any suggestions will be welcomed.

```
dput(c$estimate)
structure(c(1, 0, 0.316232734476743, 0, 0, 0.159138112996994, 
0.51716720800751, 0, 0, -0.171138157203412, -0.134403786032336, 
0, 1, 0.762712190750185, 0, 0, 0.232310016390404, -0.453603002876671, 
-0.285980739555246, 0.323373911918246, -0.291454052760697, 0, 
0.316232734476743, 0.762712190750184, 1, 0.177148045172427, 0, 
0, 0.268732694036394, 0.369995711033572, -0.424016516904762, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.177148045172423, 1, 0, -0.546060128025918, 0.501507022349682, 
0.566755462948541, 0.529918603580788, 0.129323096948468, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.159138112996997, 0.232310016390404, 
0, -0.546060128025919, 0, 1, 0.144007861096439, 0.301188044463455, 
0.481698196186874, 0.242875135784718, 0.16146544561877, 0.51716720800751, 
-0.453603002876673, 0.268732694036395, 0.501507022349684, 0, 
0.144007861096441, 1, -0.350379436564998, 0, 0.332123088063892, 
0, 0, -0.285980739555248, 0.369995711033577, 0.566755462948537, 
0, 0.301188044463452, -0.350379436564994, 1, 0, -0.141404020322527, 
0, 0, 0.323373911918248, -0.424016516904762, 0.52991860358079, 
0, 0.481698196186873, 0, 0, 1, 0.192509854303764, 0, -0.171138157203416, 
-0.291454052760697, 0, 0.129323096948465, 0, 0.242875135784717, 
0.332123088063894, -0.141404020322526, 0.192509854303766, 1, 
0, -0.134403786032336, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.16146544561877, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1), .Dim = c(11L, 11L), .Dimnames = list(c("jpm", "gs", "ms", 
"bofa", "schwab", "brk", "wf", "citi", "amex", "spgl", "pnc"), 
    c("jpm", "gs", "ms", "bofa", "schwab", "brk", "wf", "citi", 
    "amex", "spgl", "pnc")))

g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(c$estimate, weighted="wt", mode="undirected", diag=F)
evcent(g,directed=F)$vector
```

Comment: `evcent` from what package?  Is there anything in `igraph` that's relevant?

Comment: ```igraph``` package. It's the same as ```eigen_centrality``` function. @BenBolker

Comment: Someone else was wondering about definitions a few years ago: see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/82404/eigenvector-centrality-of-graph-with-negative-weights), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2487250/centrality-for-graphs-with-negative-weights)

Comment: None answered, it's a mystery! Thanks anyway @BenBolker